# Order-preserving function

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, proof-verification, order-theory

I have an order on $\mathbb R ^ \mathbb R: f \le g $ iff $\forall x \in \mathbb R: f(x) \le g(x)$. Now I have a function $\mathbb R ^ \mathbb R \to \mathbb R ^ \mathbb R: F (f)(x)= f(x^2)+1$. I have to decide, if this is function is order-preserving or not.
My train of thought: $\forall x \in \mathbb R: f(x) \le g(x) \Rightarrow f(x^2) \le g(x^2)$(just call $x^2 = y \in \mathbb R, $so$ f(y) \le g(y)$) $ \Rightarrow f(x^2)+1 \le g(x^2)+1$, so this is function is order-preserving, but I can't decide if my explanation sufficient or not.

Comment: You are essentially correct, but I don't like the way your answer is written.
You write $\forall x \in \mathbb R: f(x) \le g(x) \Rightarrow f(x^2) \le g(x^2)$ when you seem to want to say $\forall x \in \mathbb R\colon f(x) \le g(x) \Rightarrow \forall x\in \mathbb R\colon f(x^2) \le g(x^2)$. Plus the change of variables is unnecessary, but not wrong.

Comment: Good point. I can see what you don't like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you say is correct but a bit confusing. Why not just say, supposing $f\leq g$, that for $x\in\Bbb R$ one has
$$
  F(f)(x)=f(x^2)+1\leq g(x^2)+1=F(g)(x)
$$
so (since this holds for *all* $x\in\Bbb R$) one has $F(f)\leq F(g)$, and $F$ is order preserving.

Comment: Maybe that's because $f(y) \le g(y)$ $ \Rightarrow f(x^2) \le g(x^2)$ doesn't look self-explaining to me, so I add one more statement.

Comment: @DarkArchon: Well actually one uses $(\forall y: f(y)\leq g(y))\implies f(x^2)\leq g(x^2)$ which (a) makes it clear that $y$ is just a dummy variable, and (b) is just a case of instantiating a universal quantification. Afterwards one does $\forall$-introduction on $x$, but this is a very standard reasoning pattern.